# connecting to apache web server that is running on a VMWare from any device in the lan

Tags: android, networking, vmware

i am using Ubuntu (**on VMWare** on windows 7) to run an Apache web server.
i am trying to browse to this web server from my android device (using local-ip) (needless to say that the android device is connecting to the same wireless LAN of the Ubuntu and the windows 7) but no success yet.
when i browse to that web server from the windows 7 it succeed.

i have read about forwarding proxies but i want to know if this is the best solution for this problem.

Comment: There's probably nothing relevant to Android here, unless you *can* access the server from a *different* pc, but *cannot* do so from an android device on the same network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the IP address of your VMWare VM. Likely there is a virtual LAN created by VMWare, and that's how your Windows box can connect to the VM.

The simplest solution is to set up port forwarding, and forward e.g. port 8888 on your Windows box to the IP address of the VM (port 80, if your apache is configured to use the default port). Take a look at e.g. this: http://www.quantumg.net/portforward.php